# Python ignores assignment operator in editor window

Tags: python, editor, variable-assignment

I am entirely new to this (this website as well as programming), so this is probably horribly worded. I should also note that I am using python on an RPi2 so I can't paste anything. The problem is that python ignores the assignment operator when I type it into the editor, but understands it when typed into the shell. For example, if I type

```
x = 5
x
```

into the shell, the shell will respond with

```
5
```

Whereas if I type the same thing into the editor window and run the module, the shell responds with the nothing, just the restart bar and then the three arrows.

```
==========RESTART==========
.>>>
```

I can't find any information on this and I never encountered this problem using python on my desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just type `x` in your program, you basically do nothing. If you want to print it, use `print x` to explicitly tell python to print it. Note that having a plain `x` in your module would be a valid python statement (though if you were using `pyflakes` or `pylint` or other some such tool, it would cry out loud that you are not doing anything in that statement).

In the shell, this typing `x` works simply because it is the shell which supports this, it is the *shell's feature*.